# jquery image fading with tabs

Tags: jquery

Hey all, i am trying my best to figure out how to go about doing this:

I have 2 tabs. When the page loads tab1 is selected automatically. This shows the tab as 1.0 transparency while tab2 stays at 0.7.

Once the user clicks on tab2, tab1 goes to 0.7 transparency and tab2 goes to 1.0. However, i can not seem to get it to do that!

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function checkTab(theTab)
 {
     $('#tab1').fadeTo(250, 0.70);
     $('#tab2').fadeTo(250, 0.70);

     if ($("#tabActive").val() == theTab)
     {
         $(theTab).fadeTo(250, 1);
     }
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#tab1').hover(function() {$(this).fadeTo(250, 1)}, function() {checkTab('#tab1')});
     $('#tab2').hover(function() {$(this).fadeTo(250, 1)}, function() {checkTab('#tab2')});

     $('#tab2').fadeTo(250, 0.70);  
     $('#tabActive').val('tab1');
 });
 </script>

 <li class="stats"><img src="images/Stats.png" name="nav1" width="70" height="52" id="tab1" onclick="$('#tabActive').val('tab1');" /></li>
 <li class="cal"><img src="images/cal.png" name="nav1" width="70" height="52" id="tab2" onclick="$('#tabActive').val('tab2');" /></li>

 <input name="tabActive" id="tabActive" type="text" />
```

Any help would be great! :)

David

Answer (score 0):

You're entering the value `tab1` into `tabActive.val()`, but you check for `#tab1`. Decide whether you want or do not want the # in the selector =)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab1').hover(function() {$(this).fadeTo(250, 1)}, function() {checkTab('#tab1')});
    $('#tab2').hover(function() {$(this).fadeTo(250, 1)}, function() {checkTab('#tab2')});

    $('#tab2').fadeTo(250, 0.70);  
    $('#tabActive').val('#tab1');
});
```

*(And actually, a cleaner way to do it could be to just enter a number (1 or 2) and then build the string in the check function. But that's just me thinking strings look ugly in javascript and trying to avoid them...)*

Comment: Hum, i did this but it doesnt seem to help (i ended up putting the "#" on all of them)

When the page loads the tab1 is 1.0 while tab2 is 0.70 which is correct. But if i hover my house over tab2 and then off, tab1 goes to 0.7 and so does tab2.

When i hover over tab1 and then off, tab1 goes back to 1.0.

Comment: You never change the value of `$('#tabActive')`, so if you want tab 2 to stay highlighted after a simple mouse-over (and not a click or something else to select the tab) you'll have to change the value in the hover call.